# Php Curl to scape html page dynamically to last line in html page

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following php to scrape a html page. The following line specifies the lines to include:

```
for($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {
```

Can this be changed to dynamically scrape from the first line specified ($i = 7) up to the last line before the closing pre tag in the original (scraped) html file without having to specify the line number?

```
<pre style="font-size: 19px" "color:blue"><span style="color:black">
<?php
function curl_download($Url){
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
die('cURL is not installed. Install and try again.');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$start = strpos($output, '<pre>');
$end = strpos($output, '</pre>', $start);
$length = $end-$start;
$output = substr($output, $start, $length);    
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
}
$str = curl_download('http://www.atletiek.co.za/atletiek.co.za/uitslae/2016ASASASeniors/160415F002.htm');
$re = "/([^\n\r]+)/m"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
$str = "";
for($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {
$str .= $matches[$i] . "<br>"; // Preserve the new line
}
echo $str;
?>
s</pre>
```

Comment: you could break the for loop when\of you find the matching tag

Comment: Thanks mate. Any ideas how I could do this as what I have so far is the limit of my php knowledge.

Comment: in the loop `if($matches[$i]=='</pre>'){break;}`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but does the if line you propose replace the $i <= 20;?

Comment: no inside the loop: `for($i = 7; $i <= 20; $i++) {if($matches[$i]=='</pre>'){break;}
$str .= $matches[$i] . "<br>"; 
}`

Comment: It is not picking up the /pre tag and still kicks out the higher value specified. I tried changing the <= to < but it still outputs the number of lines specified. I also tried using another tag, but same result.